# Launching a stored-procedure with Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, .net, azure, stored-procedures, task-parallel-library

I am trying to develop a web service which calls a stored procedure. This stored procedure is quite long (around 1h30), and it does numerous "count" and "insert" in a database.
To launch this procedure I used a C# Class task ; here is the example :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("updateData/{date:datetime?}")]
public JsonResult UpdateData(DateTime? date) {
    try {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Data.UpdateData(date), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
         return Json("UpdateData successfully started !");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return Json("Error UpdateData: " + e);
    }
}
```

When I test in local environment it works ; but when I work on Azure the process stops after roughly 30 minutes.

For launching the web service I use the Microsoft Azure scheduler.

The problem does not seem to be the stored procedure, but it seems to be in the use of the task (because without the task it works).

Is there something special to do ?

Comment: How are you running this inside azure scheduler? Inside an ASP.NET application?

Comment: I use the Microsoft azure administration console (graphical) ; with it, punctual or periodic tasks can be launched ; I launch my web service thanks to that.

Comment: What kind of app is the web service? Class library?

Comment: The web service is a method called in a controller (ASP.NET MVC5)

Comment: I'm assuming your ASP.NET is hosted inside IIS?

Comment: yes it is inside IIS

Comment: This will **never** be reliable. Worker processes can restart for many reasons with little warning. Especially on Azure you will *never* have 90min of guaranteed uptime.

Answer (score 3):

What you're experiencing is an IIS timeout. Once IIS detects inactivity, [it will terminate the app pool](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes):

> Otherwise, when you have 20 minutes without any traffic then the app pool will terminate so that it can start up again on the next visit.

This happens because `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't register work with IIS, hence it doesn't know that you currently have active work going on.

To avoid this, If you're using .NET 4.5.2, you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` to register and queue work on a ASP.NET Threadpool thread.

If you're on previous versions, you can use [BackgroundTaskManager](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) by Stephan Cleary.

For more, read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx) by the .NET Web Development team